# Getting rid of duplicate blocks in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I've got a string broken into pairs of letters and I'm looking for a way to get rid of all the pairs of identical letters, by inserting characters in between them, to form new pairs. Further, I'm looking to split them up one pair at a time. What I've managed to do so far is put split all identical blocks simultaneously, but that's not what I'm looking for. So, for example, consider "fr ee tr ee". This should go to "fr eX et re e", not "fr eXe tr eXe".

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: TO be more clear, I need to go through the string, and at the first instance of a "double block", insert an X, and form new pairs on everything to the right of the X. SO. "AA BB", goes to "AX AB B".

So far I have

```
def FUN(text):
if len(text) < 2:
    return text

result = ""
for i in range(1, len(text), 2):
    if text[i] == text[i - 1]:
        result += text[i - 1] + "X" + text[i]
    else:
        result += text[i-1:i+1]

if len(text) % 2 != 0:
    result += text[-1]

return result
```

Comment: post the code you wrote.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough...

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense.  Say you have "fr ee tr ee ed ee ee", then that will be "fr eX et re ee de ee e".  Then that would be "fr eX et re eX ed ee ee"  Now you have two "eX"...

Comment: What happens when its `fr ee tr ee ee ee bb bb bb XX XX XX XX` ?

Comment: Mohammad, we can have blocks that are the same ("eX eX eX") would be fine, just can't have "ee" at at any instance.

Comment: I see, so "ab ab" is fine?  What about "xX"?

Comment: 'xX" would need something in between i.e. "xQ x", but I think that part could be dealt with if the rest of the code was fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ? :

```
r = list()
S = "free tree"
S = "".join(S.split())
s = list()
for i in range(0,len(S)) :
    s.append(S[i])
while len(s) > 0 :
    c1 = s.pop(0)
    c2 = 'X'
    if len(s) > 0 :
        if s[0]!=c1 :
            c2 = s.pop(0)
    else :
        c2 = ''
    r.append("{0}{1}".format(c1,c2))
result = " ".join(r)
print(result)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think this is pretty much it, thank you! what would be the easiest way to put all the printed pairs back together in one string?

Comment: str.join() is your friend :) Edited the code, have a look. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your string into a list and check each pairing in a loop then insert another character in between where you find the same character. Working on the code now will edit.

Comment: I had the same thought but my issue was [aa, bb] would be [aXa, bXb]. no? (when it ought to be [aX, ab, b]

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "freetreebreefrost"
my_parts = [my_string[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(my_string),2)]
final_list = []
while len(my_parts):
    part = my_parts.pop(0)
    if part in my_parts:
       tmp_str = part[1] +"".join(my_parts)
       my_parts = [tmp_str[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(tmp_str),2)]
       final_list.append(part[0]+"X")
    else:
       final_list.append(part)

print final_list
```

there is probably a much cooler way to do this

Comment: hmm. i'm getting "aa bb" as an output for "aabb"

Answer (score 0):

Ok here it is:

```
s = "free tree aa"

def seperateStringEveryTwoChars(s):
    # get rid of any space
    s = s.replace(' ', '')
    x = ""
    for i, l in enumerate(s, 0):
        x += l
        if i % 2:
            x += ' '
    return x.rstrip()

def findFirstDuplicateEntry(stringList):
    for i, elem in enumerate(stringList, 0):

        if len(elem) > 1 and elem[0] == elem[1]:
            return i
    return None

def yourProgram(s):

    x = seperateStringEveryTwoChars(s)
    # print x  # debug only
    splitX = x.split(' ')
    # print splitX  # debug only
    i = findFirstDuplicateEntry(splitX)
    if i == None:
        return seperateStringEveryTwoChars(s)
    # print i  # debug only
    splitX[i] = splitX[i][0] + "X" + splitX[i][1]

    # print splitX  # debug only

    s = ''.join(splitX)
    # print s  # debug only
    # print "Done"  # debug only
    return yourProgram(s)

print yourProgram(s)
```

Output:

fr eX et re ea a

with an input of string of "aabbccddd" it will output "aX ab bc cd dX d"

Comment: the ouput has an extra "X".  "fr eX et re e" has a space between the last two "e"'s, there's no need to put anything there

Comment: so what you want is that every time you find a double pair add the x and then split the string again see if the new string contains any more double pairs ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple 3 lines of code solution, single pass, as easy as it gets.
No splitting, joining, arrays, for loops, nothing.

1. First, remove all spaces from the string, Replace_All `\s+` with ""
2. Replace_All with callback `((.)(?:(?!\2)(.)|)(?!$))`
   a. if (matched $3) replace with $1
   b. else replace with $1+"X"
3. Finally, put a space between every 2 chars. Replace_All `(..)` with $1 + " "

This is a test using Perl (don't know Python that well)

```
 $str = 'ee ee rx xx tt bb ff fr ee tr ee';

 $str =~ s/\s+//g;
 $str =~ s/((.)(?:(?!\2)(.)|)(?!$))/ defined $3 ? "$1" : "$1X"/eg;
 $str =~ s/(..)/$1 /g;

 print $str,"\n";

 # Output:     
 # eX eX eX er xX xX xt tb bf fX fr eX et re e
```

---

```
 # Expanded regex
 #
 (                        # (1 start)
      ( . )               # (2)
      (?:
           (?! \2 )       # Not equal to the first char?
           ( . )          # (3) Grab the next one
        |  
                          # or matches the first, an X will be inserted here
      )
      (?! $ )
 )                        # (1 end)
```